Weird gcc maybe-unitialized in if
I have a warning I don't understand in a templated function. How can the value be not initialized if its the if condition?
Note: the warning disappear if I remove std::vector<std::byte> from the variant
My simplified code:
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <type_traits>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

struct INOValue : std::variant<uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, uint64_t, int64_t, std::vector<std::byte>>
{
    using variant::variant;
};

template <typename T> constexpr T ToBiggerVariable( INOValue aVariable )
{
    if constexpr( std::is_same<T, uint64_t>::value )
    {
        uint64_t lReturn = 0;
        if ( auto *lPointer = std::get_if<uint8_t>( &aVariable ) )
        {
            lReturn = *lPointer;
        }
        else if( auto *lPointer2 = std::get_if<uint16_t>( &aVariable ) )
        {
            lReturn = *lPointer2;
        }
        else if( auto *lPointer3 = std::get_if<uint32_t>( &aVariable ) )
        {
            lReturn = *lPointer3;
        }
        else if( auto *lPointer4 = std::get_if<uint64_t>( &aVariable ) )
        {
            lReturn = *lPointer4;
        }
        else
        {
            throw std::logic_error( "Invalid conversion to uint64" );
        }
        return lReturn;
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::logic_error( "Type not handled" );
    }
}

int main()
{
    INOValue lValue        = uint64_t( 12345 );
    const uint64_t lValue2 = ToBiggerVariable<uint64_t>( lValue );
    if( lValue2 > 0 )
        std::cout << "OK";
    return 0;
}

I have the same warning for lPointer2 and lPointer3
Warning     ‘*(unsigned int*)((char*)&<unnamed> + offsetof(INOValue, INOValue::<unnamed>.std::variant<unsigned char, short unsigned int, unsigned int, long unsigned int, long int, std::vector<std::byte, std::allocator<std::byte> > >::<unnamed>.std::__detail::__variant::_Variant_base<unsigned char, short unsigned int, unsigned int, long unsigned int, long int, std::vector<std::byte, std::allocator<std::byte> > >::<unnamed>.std::__detail::__variant::_Move_assign_base<false, unsigned char, short unsigned int, unsigned int, long unsigned int, long int, std::vector<std::byte, std::allocator<std::byte> > >::<unnamed>.std::__detail::__variant::_Copy_assign_base<false, unsigned char, short unsigned int, unsigned int, long unsigned int, long int, std::vector<std::byte, std::allocator<std::byte> > >::<unnamed>.std::__detail::__variant::_Move_ctor_base<false, unsigned char, short unsigned int, unsigned int, long unsigned int, long int, std::vector<std::byte, std::allocator<std::byte> > >::<unnamed>.std::__detail::__variant::_Copy_ctor_base<false, unsigned char, short unsigned int, unsigned int, long unsigned int, long int, std::vector<std::byte, std::allocator<std::byte> > >::<unnamed>.std::__detail::__variant::_Variant_storage<false, unsigned char, short unsigned int, unsigned int, long unsigned int, long int, std::vector<std::byte, std::allocator<std::byte> > >::_M_u))’ may be used uninitialized [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]


My CMakelists if its useful:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(test_init
    LANGUAGES CXX
)

if(MSVC)
    add_compile_options(/W4)
    add_compile_options(/we4706 /we4275) #Assignement in if && dll link
else(MSVC)
    set(cxx_flags -Wsuggest-override -Werror=suggest-override)
    add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wno-unknown-pragmas)
endif(MSVC)

add_executable(test_init main.cpp)

set_target_properties(test_init PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 17
    CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES
    CXX_EXTENSIONS NO
)

gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)
It's happening both with WSL and on a docker. Both based on ubuntu 22.04
Dockerfile used (minus specific install i.e openCV and Qt):
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN apt -y update && \
    apt -y upgrade && \
    apt-get -y install \
    build-essential \
    gdb \
    ninja-build \
    cmake \
    wget \
    unzip \
    git \
    python3 \
    python3-pip \
    curl \
    cppcheck \
    sudo


Compiles without errors or warnings and prints "OK"  in g++ 13.2.1  Is this an MSVC problem?

What gcc version is this occuring in?

its built on ubuntu 22.04, gcc 11.4(added more detail in question)

Not seeing it on godbolt

BTW, you misspelt std::uint8_t etc.  Best to make your code compilable by as much of the audience as possible, rather than relying on non-portable assumptions.

I can't repro this on GCC 14.0.1, nor if I go back to 11.4.0 (both on Debian).  Is it down to the version of the Standard Library you're using?

How can I check that? It's based on ubuntu 22.04. I have added the dockerfile I use

Perhaps start with aptitude -F '%v %p' search '~i lib(c|stdc)\+\+ -dev'?

11.4.0-1ubuntu libstdc++-11-dev
